# Logstash Custom match patterns

Tags: logstash

We are in the process of capturing the logstash

2016-01-07 13:12:36,718 82745269 [http-nio-10180-exec-609] 8ca2b394-f435-4376-9a16-8be44ad437b9 - entry:"dummy-AS-1.1"

we are having logs like this,We want how to match the messages .Once matched we want to remove 82745269 and [http-nio-10180-exec-609].Pls help

Answer (score 1):

How do you match them?  With the [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html).

How do you make a grok pattern?  Slowly, using [the debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Maybe [an introduction](http://svops.com/blog/introduction-to-logstash-grok-patterns/) would help.